# ADFS - change adfs default login page to aws console login page

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, authorization, saml, adfs

I have set up ADFS and successfully integrated the same with AWS. My users are able to login to the AWS console using the ADFS default login page.

```
https://servername.companyname.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx
```

Everything is working fine. My only concern is why should my users remember this full URL. They should log in using the URL which is easy to remember. I have done some research where I understand that I can create the redirect entry and forward all requests.

I don't want to do that, I would prefer my users to login using a URL like AWS console. I do the research whether I can allow my users to log in through the AWS console page using their AD credentials but did not find any helpful information.

I have also gone through the AWS AD connector where Active directory can be linked to AWS. But I am not sure this will resolve my problem.

I believe someone has gone through the same problem, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using the AD Connector. Initially, I was facing issues to connect the AD with AWS AD Connector because of the IP of my EC2 on which AD is running.

After you set up the AD Connector, they asked you to create an Access URL which looks like

```
https://<yourAppPrefix>.awsapps.com/console
```

So when your users hit above URL you will get AWS Console login page which looks like
[image]

So when the user login to this, they will be redirected to the AWS Console.

Note: You will need to ADD a role in IAM that will be added to the AD Connector and you can bind the AD user or groups to these roles.

Answer (score 1):

If the app (in this case AWS) supports SP initiated flows, you can go to the app URL which will redirect you to ADFS. This is usually the more common approach. I believe AWS supports SP initiated login. Do check on the AWS site.

Some apps support IDP initiated flows which ADFS supports as well. The goal for IPD initiated flow was to ensure that you can build links (let's say in a portal) for people to click which will authenticate them first and then redirect them to the application.

Thanks //Sam (@MrADFS)